# Why does $status = 0 After Using curl_exec($curl)?

Tags: php, json, post, curl, docusignapi

I'm trying to create a [recipientView](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeViews&operations=createRecipient&mode=basic) using the DocuSign API. I'm trying to POST a request in PHP using the cURL library but for some reason when executing my code, the line `$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` in my code below is returning 0:

```
$url = "http://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/$account_id/envelopes/
        $envelope_id/views/recipient";

$body = array("returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
                "authenticationMethod" => "None", 
                "email" => "$recipient",
                "userName" => "$recipient");

$body_string = json_encode($body);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body_string),
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_string);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $status;

$response = json_decode($jason_response, true);
$url = $response["url"];
```

I am sending the POST via JSON and the response I am supposed to get back is JSON. Why is it that my `curl_exec()` is failing and making `$status = 0`?

Comment: Try adding `curl_error($curl)` after the `curl_exec` call and see if that returns any error message.

Comment: When doing this the error is: Failed to connect to demo.docusign.net port 80: Connection refused

Comment: That's the problem, then. I added an answer with this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your error message

```
Failed to connect to demo.docusign.net port 80: Connection refused
```

Is that you are attempting to connect to HTTP port 80 but docusign.net only listens to HTTPS port 443.

Change API URL from `http://` to `https://` and you should be set and the `curl_getinfo()` will return the correct value as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're not including an authentication header. Each call to the API needs to be authenticated.

[Docs about Authentication options](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html)

Comment: Even when I add an authentication header (using an access token) I get the same response. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

When there is an error during `curl_exec`, the result of `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` will be zero. Since you found that `curl_error` returned the following:

> Failed to connect to demo.docusign.net port 80: Connection refused

the result is zero.

You will have to figure out why DocuSign is refusing your connection (check their API documentation). Once you figure that out and fix it, you should get a correct JSON result back as well as have a valid HTTP status code.